# Attempt to invoke on a null object while destructuring in a for loop

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How is this even possible?

On a background thread, I'm running some computation that populates a list, then invalidates a view, and the view runs onDraw.

```
var list = mutableListOf<Pair<DataPoint, String>>()
```

...

```
generateBgData() {
    list.clear()
    list.add(...,...)
    invalidate()
}
```

In onDraw, I make a copy of the list, so as to prevent updates to the list from causing errors,

```
    val listCopy = ArrayList(list)
    for ((point, str)in listCopy) { // Null exception thrown here
        canvas.drawText(...)
    }
```

But on the line noted, I'm getting a null object reference error while destructuring `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object kotlin.Pair.component1()' on a null object reference`. How is this even possible? My list is non-null, and nowhere do I ever set the list to null. If it is empty, the for loop should never run. I recreated the code running the issue [here](https://pl.kotl.in/0bzEIq1lF), and can't replicate it, but it happens very infrequently in my app on the play store.

Any idea what could possibly be happening?

Comment: The error is telling you that an item in the list is null, not the list itself. Is it possible it was declared as `List<Pair<DataPoint, String>?>` anywhere, or cast anywhere? Any multithreading?

Comment: @Tenfour04 it is not declared as optional, and none of the values are. There is multi-threading, the .clear(), .add(), and invalidate() are called on a background thread, while the for loop runs on the main thread, but at no point is the list or any element ever nullable

Comment: @Tenfour04 would synchronizing the list solve this?

Comment: I think so if you wrap anything that manipulates the list, as well as the `val listCopy = (list)` using the same synchronized lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multi-threading is probably the culprit. Imagine your list has some items in it when this code runs:

```
val listCopy = ArrayList(list)
```

While the ArrayList constructor is copying items out of the list, the other thread clears the list, which marks everything null. If the other thread is faster at clearing the list than this thread is at copying the references over, it will start copying null references over for the last items in the list.

I recommend exclusively using read-only lists if you are modifying the data from multiple threads.